# Oracle multitenant - execute PL/SQL, over DBMS_SQL, in another container

Tags: oracle, plsql, multi-tenant, pdb

The documentation says that

```
execute immediate 'alter session set container=myPDB'
```

is disabled from PDBs ( possible from the CDB Root and also Application Container ),

but it says nothing against DBMS_SQL.PARSE. 
I expected that it would be able to execute PL/SQL, from PDB, in another PDB, over DBMS_SQL.PARSE but have got the the error:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

So, look like it is also impossible like that.
The test is the following

I login in CDB Root as SYSDBA.

I am then able to execute the following:

```
declare
c1 int;
rowsn integer;
statem varchar2(500);
ctx    varchar2(128);
BEGIN
    c1 := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    ctx :='myPDB';
    statem :='  declare
                                var1 varchar2(60);
                                begin
                                select user into var1 from dual;
                                end;';
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c => c1 ,
                   statement => statem,
                   language_flag => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                   container => ctx);

  rowsn:=DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c=>c1);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c=>c1);
END;
/
```

and it works !

but once I switch to the PDB as

```
alter session set container=myPDB;
```

I am not any more able to do the following

```
alter session set container=myPDB;


declare
c1 int;
rowsn integer;
statem varchar2(500);
ctx    varchar2(128);
BEGIN
    c1 := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    ctx :='myPDB2';
    statem :='  declare
                                var1 varchar2(60);
                                begin
                                select user into var1 from dual;
                                end;';
   DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c => c1 ,
                   statement => statem,
                   language_flag => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                   container => ctx);

  rowsn:=DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c=>c1);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c=>c1);
END;
/
```

any possibility to be able to execute PL/SQL from PDB, inside another PDB, over DBMS_SQL.PARSE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDBs are effectively separate databases, with separate security (users, roles, privileges, etc.). There is no visibility between them. You would have to treat them like independent, stand-alone databases. The only way stand-alone Oracle databases can interact is through database links.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `alter session set container` command inside pl/sql. It is only available in sql/sqlplus for easy access or manage. As it is clearly stated in the Oracle application container documentation, cross-data cannot be read from parallel-level pdbs. Data reading can only be done via root. No need for sysdba privilege to read data. The user only needs container_data=all option. You can set it with this command `alter user <username> set container_data=all container=current`. Also note that, user should be created on the root pdb and synchronized to the sub pdbs.